# gridwidth is not the same for all gridlines

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am facing a problem with the `gridwidth` not the same for all grid lines. The thickest lines vary when you zoom-in and zoom-out. I need to make all grid lines have the same width.
Thank you for your help.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", facet_col="species")
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='black')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting the `gridwidth` to a value less than 1. The issue may be in how the grid line locations align (or don't) with the pixel locations. The effect you see when zooming makes me suspect this.

Comment: @blarg Unfortunately, I changed a lot of values less than 1, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally a problem of rendering. You might have this problem becuase you are using Jupyter notebook as me. It can be solved with two options:

- Change the default rendering which is `notebook` to `svg` or `browser`. You should simply use:

  ```
  fig.show(renderer="browser")
  ```

  [image]
- Second option is to increase the value of `gridwidth` to 2

[image]

If we increase the `gridwidth` more than 2, the problem is solved more significantly.

With `gridwidth=3`:
[image]

**Last note**
The issue is only when we plot over the browser, but when I download the image and open it, all lines of the grid have the same width. The image below is the downloaded image with `gridwidth=1` which is the same in the question:

[image]