# plotly line chart zero line color

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

er,

I have two questions:

1. grid thickness:
   the vertical grid line on the date Jan 2024 is much thicker than other peers. why?
2. zero line color:
   as you can see on the plot, the color of white line (zero line) is what I want to change.
   It is simply not the x axis. So, how to change the color? Ideally, it can be set to dark.
   [image]

this is my code

```
    def plot_line(self):
    df = self.rolling_cor()

    """plot"""
    # plot single line
    fig = px.line(df, x=df.iloc[:, 0], y=df.iloc[:, 1])
    fig.update_traces(line_color='#2F0063', line_width=1.5)
    fig.update_xaxes(color="#000000", linecolor='#000000', gridcolor='#C6C6C6', title_text=f'date')
    fig.update_yaxes(color="#000000", linecolor='#000000', gridcolor='#C6C6C6', title_text=f'correlation')
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, title=df.columns[1],
                      title_font_size=30, title_x=0.5,
                      font_family="Arial",
                      paper_bgcolor="#FFE2DC",
                      plot_bgcolor="#FFE2DC")

    # annotate last quote - first
    fig.add_scatter(x=[fig.data[0].x[0]], y=[fig.data[0].y[0]],
                    mode='markers + text',
                    marker={'color': 'blue', 'size': 14},
                    showlegend=False,
                    text=[fig.data[0].y[0]],
                    textposition='middle left')
    # annotate last quote - last
    fig.add_scatter(x=[fig.data[0].x[-1]], y=[fig.data[0].y[-1]],
                    mode='markers + text',
                    marker={'color': 'red', 'size': 14},
                    showlegend=False,
                    text=[fig.data[0].y[-1]],
                    textposition='middle right')

    # add annotation
    anno_p1 = "As of "
    anno_p2 = str(df.iloc[len(df) - 1, 0])[:10]
    anno_p3 = ", "
    anno_p4 = "the quote is at "
    anno_p5 = str(round(df.iloc[len(df) - 1, 1], 2))
    anno_text = "".join([anno_p1, anno_p2, anno_p3, anno_p4, anno_p5])
    fig.add_annotation(
        dict(font=dict(color='#2F0063', size=25),
             x=0, y=-0.09,
             showarrow=False,
             text=anno_text,
             textangle=0,
             xanchor='left',
             xref="paper",
             yref="paper"))

    fig.show()
```

Comment: regarding the issue of the thickness, I check the q&a but it does not work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71819086/gridwidth-is-not-the-same-for-all-gridlines

Comment: regarding the zero line: it doesn't work if I update_layout, I think it is not called zero line:
xaxis=dict(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor="gray", zeroline=True, zerolinecolor='red')

Comment: According to the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#styling-zero-lines), the following code should be able to handle this, `fig.update_xaxes(zeroline=True, zerolinewidth=2, zerolinecolor='LightPink')` but for some reason it does not change. The workaround is to create a graph and then set the graph theme to no graph theme, which will make it black. `fig = px.line(df, x=df.iloc[:, 0], y=df.iloc[:, 1]-1);fig.update_layout(template=None)` However, editing the color directly does not change it. It may be that this setting is done deeper in the code.

Comment: @r-beginners
thx, `fig.update_layout(template=None)` works. It turns into black.